# How to create a touch event for all other views except one view on iPad screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my iPad application,  there're multiple views shown on screen. I hope to create a touch down event for all other shown views except one view? How can I do it? ( i can create touch event one by one view, but i think that's not a good idea)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple...

just write touch begin like....

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view]!=< your view that you dont want to touch >)
    {
       // <# Your Code #>
    }
}
```